# Manipulate data returned from server in Angular 2 without using pipes

Tags: angular

Here's a simple Angular 2 class I'm using:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Which data is bound using a `.map` in `http.get`:

```
export class LogService {

    constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http) {}
    ... 
    return this.http.get(myGlobals.API_URL).map(this.extractData) 
    ...
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
}
```

Here is the component code which calls the LogService class (log.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LogEntry } from './log';
import { LogService } from './log.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'log-list',
  templateUrl: './log-list.component.html',
  providers: [ LogService ]
})
export class LogListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  logEntries: LogEntry[];
  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor (private LogService: LogService) {}

  ngOnInit() { this.getLog(); }

  getLog() {
    this.logService.getLog()
                .subscribe(
                    logs=> this.logEntries = logs,
                    error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
```

}

Here is the HTML template I'm using to display the data:

```
<div *ngFor="let logEntry of logEntries" class="row">
    <div class="cell">{{logEntry.id}}</div>
    <div class="cell">{{logEntry.company}}</div>
    <div class="cell">{{logEntry.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Now Let's say I want to manipulate the data before it's displayed in the HTML.
For instance: I want to `trim()` or `replace()` the string returned for `logEntry.name` - **without** the hassle of creating a **pipe** for each of the operations.

Is that possible ?

Thanks everybody.

Comment: post the code where you call LogService, where you assign LogEntries

Comment: I added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filter and do whatever amendments,

```
 getLog() {
    this.logService.getLog()
                .subscribe(
                    logs=> this.logEntries = logs,
                    error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    this.logEntries = this.logEntries.filter(element => {
             return element.name.trim();
       });
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting: EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: No... It's now allowed in my company :(

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is OK ? I just copy+pasted it

Comment: lol, I'm sorry man! I'm going through my unaccepted questions and saw this. Well - better later then ever. Peace and love from Israel mate.